# Create a program that extracts the vowels from the alphabet

Tags: vb.net

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim alphabet() As String = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"}
    Dim vowel As New List(Of String)
    vowel.Add("a")
    vowel.Add("e")
    vowel.Add("i")
    vowel.Add("o")
    vowel.Add("u")


    Next
End Sub

End Module
```

I am new to coding and not sure how to create a for loop which checks each value in the array "alphabet" to check if it's a vowel, the program should then output the vowels in order.

Comment: The two main things you'll need: A [**`For Each` loop**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx) and the [**`List(Of T).Contains()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim alphabet() As String = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"}
    For Each element As String In alphabet
        If element = "a" Then
            Console.Write("a")
        End If
        If element = "e" Then
            Console.Write("e")
        End If
        If element = "i" Then
            Console.Write("i")
        End If
        If element = "o" Then
            Console.Write("o")
        End If
        If element = "u" Then
            Console.Write("u")
        End If
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: You should learn about the [Select...Case Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx).